# curl requests to nginx:alpine docker image being rejected Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

Tags: docker

I'm trying to debug why my curl requests being sent to a docker container are being rejected on my ubuntu 20.04 machine. I'm running the stock `nginx:alpine` image.

```
chris@chris-Precision-7920-Tower  ~  docker images                                                                                                                               
nginx          alpine                  629df02b47c8   2 months ago    22.3MB
hello-world    latest                  bf756fb1ae65   13 months ago   13.3kB
openjdk        8-jdk-alpine            a3562aa0b991   21 months ago   105MB
 chris@chris-Precision-7920-Tower  ~  docker run  -p 8081:80 nginx:alpine                                                                                                           ✔  5437  08:20:32
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Enabled listen on IPv6 in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
```

and then i try to send a request to the container with

```
curl http://0.0.0.0:8081/
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

I've had this happen to me on more sophisticated images/containers, but this seems to be the minimal reproducible example. With my more sophisticated examples, i have made sure to bind to `0.0.0.0` rather than `127.0.0.1`/`localhost` inside of the container.

docker versions

```
chris@chris-Precision-7920-Tower  ~  docker --version                        ✔  5447  08:39:08
Docker version 20.10.3, build 48d30b5
 chris@chris-Precision-7920-Tower  ~  dockerd --version                       ✔  5449  08:46:24
Docker version 20.10.3, build 46229ca
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dummies (like myself) in the future that have this problem, this was caused by my VPN.

Everything works as expected once my VPN is turned off.